# git checkout certain commit detached

Tags: git

Due to some wrong commits to master by another developer I had to perform git checkout to certain commit, now:

```
git branch
```

shows

```
* detached from (certain commit)
master
```

I've fixed master now, how to I remove this *detached branch and turn on master again?

Answer (score 1):

> how to I remove this *detached branch and turn on master again?

Create a local branch.

```
git checkout -b SOME_BRANCH_NAME
```

In detached `HEAD` state the `HEAD` points to a commit and not to a branch.

```
HEAD --->  commit
```

If you create a local branch your `HEAD` will point to that branch and that branch will point to the commit.

```
HEAD ---> SOME_BRANCH_NAME ---> commit
```

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout master` will move from `detached HEAD` to `HEAD`.